# Local copies of arrays for threads in OpenMP?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, openmp

I am new to OpenMP so this might be very basic.
I have a function:

```
void do_calc(int input1[], int input2[], int results[]);
```

Now, the function modifies `input1[]` during calculations but still can use it for another iteration (it sorts it in various ways), `input2[]` is different for every iteration and the function stores results in `results[]`.

In one threaded version of the program I just iterate through various `input2[]`. In parallel version I try this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:counter) schedule(static) private (i,j)
for (i = 0; i < NUMITER ; i++){
    int tempinput1[1000];
    int tempresults[1000];
    int tempinput2[5] = derive_input_from_i(i, input2[]);
    array_copy(input, tempinput);
    do_calc(tempinput, tempinput2, tempresults);
    for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        counter += tempresults[i] //simplified 
}
```

This code works but is very inefficient because I am copying input to `tempinput` every iteration and I need only one copy per thread. This copy could be then reused in subsequent `do_calc` invocations. What I would like to do is this:

```
#do this only once for every thread worker:
array_copy(input, tempinput);
```

and then tell the thread to store `tempinput` for iterations it does in the future.
How do I go about it in OpenMP?

Additional performance issues:

a) I would like to have the code which works on dual/quad/octal core processors and let OpenMP determine number of thread workers and for every of them copy input once;

b) My algorithm benefits from `input[]` being sorted in previous iteration (as then next sort is faster as keys change only slightly for similar i's) so I would like to make sure that number of iterations is divided equally among threads and that thread no 1 gets `0 ... NUMITER/n` portion of iterations, thread no 2 gets `NUMITER/n ... 2*NUMITER/n` etc.

b) Is not that important but it would be very cool to have :)

(I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I have OpenMP 2.0 version)

Comment: I probably don't understand exactly what it is you're doing, but if 'tempinput' only needs to be calculated once, you could create it outside any OpenMP directives, set it's value however you want (possibly in another OpenMP loop) and then in the for directive in question, just use the established array.

Comment: yep, but every thread need its own copy of input (because calc function is accessing it/swapping elements on it); I implemented workaround for this "reimplementing" for directive in normal parallel directive (by manually calculating size of chunks and running every thread with different chunk of all iterations but it still feels like just a work around although performance is now perfect 2x on my dual core.

Comment: oh, then just copy the input outside the directive and make tempinput "private"

Comment: Right, and then I can just add "pragma omp for private(i)" inside the bigger parallel block instead simulating for manually. I messed it up by trying "pragma omp parallel for" instead thus doubling parallel and executing everything 2 times. Thanks!